# How to get custom Id from AspNetUsers table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently working on a website which is being developed in ASP.NET and C#. To get the`UserId` from `AspNetUsers` table by simply doing `User.Identity.GetUserId()` which returns something like `m13t79j0-4p5e-829h-4x10-fyv74k0w2ff6`. Now I need to change this to a custom `UserId` which will be an `int` so something like

```
1
2
3
and so on
```

In the `IdentityModel` I have the following code to point to the table custom table and Id

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("CustomTable").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("MyCustomId");
    }
```

However when I do `User.Identity.GetUserId()` it still returns this id `User.Identity.GetUserId()`. I'm fairly new to C# and ASP.NET so can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Do I have to override the `GetUserId()` method? Thanks in advance for all your help and support

Comment: [`IdentityExtensions.GetUserId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityextensions.getuserid(v=vs.108).aspx) is an extension method. You cannot override an extension but you could provide another.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Can you elaborate a little please?

Comment: @Downvoter care to say why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you have to relate the AspNetUsers table from Asp.Net Identity with your current Users table. One possibility to achieve it is creating a new column (foreign key) in AspNetUsers table with your current UserId from Users table like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var applicationUser = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(u => u.Id).ToTable("Users", "dbo");
    applicationUser.Property(iu => iu.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
    ...
```

Or just adding a new table with the relationship as you did in your question.

**Web Api**

Then you can override the `OnAuthorizationAsync` method from `AuthorizeAttribute` and get your UserId from Db using `Principal.Identity.GetUserId()`:

```
public class WebApiAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

        Guid userId;

        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            && Guid.TryParse(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId(), out userId))
        {
            ApplicationUserManager manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(new ApplicationDbContext())) { PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher() };

            ApplicationUser user = await manager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

            actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("MyCustomId", user.MyCustomId);
        }
    }
}
```

To retrieve the value on you controller action do:

```
object MyCustomId;
Request.Properties.TryGetValue("MyCustomId", out MyCustomId);
```

**ASP.NET MVC**

For ASP.Net MVC override OnAuthorization instead of OnAuthorizationAsync:

```
public class MvcAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userId = new Guid(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

            ApplicationUserManager manager =
                new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(new ApplicationDbContext()))
                {
                    PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher()
                };

            var user = manager.FindById(userId);

            actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("MyCustomId", user.MyCustomId);            
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I get an error no method `OnAuthorizationAsync` to override. I'm pretty new to C# so do excuse me if I'm making an obvious mistake

Comment: @Code Try with OnAuthorization instead of OnAuthorizationAsync. You should be using ASP.Net Mvc instead of ASP.Net Web Api, shouldn't you?

Comment: I'm not using ASP.NET MVC. I'm picking the project up more than halfway through the development lifecycle so can't really change it to MVC either

Comment: @Code At the end, what you have to do is only retrieve from Db the UserId using User.Identity.GetUserId() as a parameter. Something like "Select UserId from AspNetUsers Where Id = 'm13t79j0-4p5e-829h-4x10-fyv74k0w2ff6'". So use the Code of OnModelCreaing that I've posted and then try to retrieve the UserId on the place you need it querying the Db.

Comment: I can retrieve the normal UserId no problem I want to retrieve a custom Id which will be an `int` instead of the long UserId `'m13t79j0-4p5e-829h-4x10-fyv74k0w2ff6`

Comment: @Code Then you have to access to Db to retrieve the int UserId using the Guid UserId as a filter. Example: "Select UserId from AspNetUsers Where Id = 'm13t79j0-4p5e-829h-4x10-fyv74k0w2ff6'

Comment: Right, I understand what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var curretlyLoggedInUserId = (((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User).Claims).ToList()[0].Value;
```

This gets me the Id from the AspNetUsers Table in ASP.